# Which private framework allows for access to auto-lock on iOS?

Tags: ios

I am trying to create a personal app for myself that allows me to keep my iPhone on for extended periods of time as a way to save time and as a learning project.

I want to be able to do that from my app and have a timer that changes the auto lock off back to its default setting.

I have realized I might be able to do this from a private framework, except I don’t know which one.

I have already tried `UIApplication.shared.isIdleTimerDisabled = true`, and have tried to look for a API that does this. Is there an framework for this?

Comment: `UIApplication.shared.isIdleTimerDisabled = true` disables the "auto-lock" ... setting it to `false` re-enables it. Did that not work for you?

Comment: I want to be able to change to something like the files app while this app is running in the background, when I leave the app auto-lock is re-enabled

Comment: Ah - so your goal is to have your app disable auto-lock *globally* ... Unlikely that you'll find a way to do that, even trying to use a "private api" -- unless you get into jailbreaking your phone.

Comment: If that is the case, is there a way to emulate something similar to the caffeinate command? Is there a way to emulate clicks every 10 to 20 seconds?

Comment: Apple has done a lot to prevent apps from "taking over control" of devices. You *could* look into methods to keep your app "alive" - search for `swift keep app running in background` ... but I don't know of anything you can do from the background to prevent screen-lock. Unless this is a "figure out how to do it" exercise for you, it seems like a lot more work than simply opening the Settings app and setting "Auto-Lock: Never" while you're working...